# Is there a way to show the Key filters section "MetadataNavKeyFilters.ascx" inside my enterprise wiki pages (not only on the list view)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, user-controls, metadata-navigation

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside sharepoint server 2013. and i have enabled metadata navigation & filtering for the wiki pages list . Now when i click on any list view i will get the key filters section which is a user control named `MetadataNavKeyFilters.ascx` i as follow:-

[image]

but when i am reading a wiki page (for example the welcome wiki page) the "key filters" section will not be shown. as seems by defualt the key filter section will be shown inside the list views only,while it will not be shown on the wiki pages welcome page and other pages... so can any one adivce if i can show the "Key Filters" section when viewing the wiki page (under the site navigation links if possible)?

Thanks

**Edit** Now i edit the master page and i add the following at the beginning of the master page, to register the MetadataNavKeyFilters.ascx:-

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="MetadataNavKeyFilters" src="~/_controltemplates/15/MetadataNavKeyFilters.ascx" %>
```

but not sure what i need to do next ,, to be able to show this control under the site navigation link ? or this approach will not work at the end ?

Comment: When you are viewing a single wiki page, what would you expect to happen after applying a key filter?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could connect a Filter Web Part to a View of your Document library.

Ref; https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Filter-Web-Part-to-a-List-View-Web-Part-4F3F6C10-0A1B-479D-8B4D-C4F1BF49BB3F

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will look into your link, but there is not a way to reference the existing MetadataNavKeyFilters.ascx under the site navigation links ?

Comment: There's certainly no OOTB way, as Key Filters are applied list view pages only I'm afraid.

Comment: ok i see ,, but what are the options to have similar functionalities ? now in my case enterprise wiki are contained within a page layout ,, so do you mean i can add a filter web art to the page layout ?

Comment: You can add filters and connect them to your view.

Answer (score 1):

This control passes filter parameters to a list view. What is it supposed to do on random wiki-page? It's somewhat understandable if your wikipage contains a webpart that displays document library where MMS navigation is active (list view). An approach to the closest you can get it to work is described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/web_part_page_and_metadata_navigation/archive/2012/05/16/web-part-page-and-metadata-navigation.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i agree with you, but this is what our customer requested,, that when reading wiki pages they want to be able to filter the wiki pages without having to go to a list view ...so i want the current filters that are being shown inside the list view , to be also under the site navigation link when viewing wiki pages... is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Could you please explain what's customer requesting? What is SP to do when user clicks on Apply while on wikipage? Navigate back to default view of doclib?

Comment: your point is valid, and from my side i am happy with that SP offers regarding this. but the requirement is as follow:- Now when you navigate to the wiki home page let say "http://servername/wiki" you will see the wiki welcome page + wiki category on right + site links on the left... now i want to be showing the filters above the site navigation links... now they can click on a list view and they can do the filters they want,,, but they requested that they want to see the filter fields without having to navigate to the list view !!

Comment: What one can do is 1. Develop custom nav web part that looks like MetadataNavKeyFilters control 2. Modify page layout that's in use (by default it's _catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx) to include new web part zone, and put custom nav web part in ZoneTemplate so it will be shown on all pages

Comment: thanks for the reply,, seems a valid approach , but can you please give me useful links about how i can develop a nav web part ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iK8IPUB87w as a sample. In your webpart, first you get MetadataNavigationSettings of that doclib, then use FindConfiguredKeyFilter method for each field ('Standard' and 'Document Type' in your case), then render the UI that looks similar to native. Your webpart will browse to new location when 'Apply' is clicked - namely, to the default view of a doclib - while also submitting filter values... I'm not sure it's worth it